# How does 3cm microwave pass through a 0.5 cm grating?

Tags: waves, microwaves, light-emitting-diodes

This YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nQMHvwmZl4) prompted a question. If the wavelength of the PASCO microwave generator is about 3 cm, how do we explain that a significant portion passes through a 1/2 $cm^2$ screen? I have a naive impression that the wave won't pass through an opening significantly smaller than the wavelength.

My guess is some variation of the idea that the wave is both reflected and propagated at the screen, and the propagated part reassembles on the other side...?

I have noticed this with my microwave oven too. The screen is supposed to shield and mostly does, but there is a strong and measurable reading across a room on my cheapo RF detector.

It seems reasonable that energy can get through "gaps" in the shielding, but I am not sure what the precise explanation should be, or how to visualize this. (I assume the Gunn diode partially polarizes the light but this does not really change the question).

(This is a cross-post from the Chemistry site at the suggestion of a senior member).

Comment: a screen in which the wavelength to gap ratio ~6 is essentially transparent, even with a gap ratio higher than 20 anything better than -30dB leakage is difficult because of diffraction around the frame edges,  and to get anything much better you need real setup with absorbers all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[General rule of thumb is that the opening in a Faraday cage should be smaller than 1/10th of the wavelength  that should be blocked. For example, in order to block EM fields with frequencies of 10 GHz and lower, the hole size of the Faraday cage should be smaller than 3 mm.](https://www.gamry.com/application-notes/instrumentation/faraday-cage/#:%7E:text=General%20rule%20of%20thumb%20is,be%20smaller%20than%203%20mm.)